# No viable overloaded '=' when assigning an object to another

Tags: c++

My class `Graf` looks like this:

```
class graf{
private:
    int n, m;
    nod a[100];
public:
    graf(int n, int m);
    graf operator~();
};
```

My class `nod` looks like this:

```
class nod{
private:
    muchie *a;
public:
    nod();
    nod(nod &x);
    ~nod();
    nod &operator=(nod &x){
        int i;
        this->id=x.id;
        this->nr=x.nr;
        for(i=0;i<=nr;i++) this->a[i]=x.a[i];
        return *this;
    }
    void operator+(nod &y);
};
```

When I try to run the simple code below, the compiler will say: `No viable overloaded '='`. If I delete the '=' overcharge within `nod`, there will be no error, so I guess the problem is with this overcharge? I really can't figure out what is wrong.

```
graf gt(4,4);
gt=~g;    // where g is an already declared graf
```

The problem isn't the `~` overcharge, I tried it without the overcharging of `=` and it could run the code properply.

Edit:

```
graf graf::operator~(){
    nod nodc;
    int i,j;
    graf gt(this->getN(), this->getM());

    for(i=1;i<=this->getN();i++){
        nodc=this->getNode(i);
        for(j=0;j<=nodc.getNr();j++){
            gt.getNode(nodc.getMuchie(j).getY()->getId()) + (gt.getNode(nodc.getMuchie(j).getY()->getId()), gt.getNode(i));
        }
    }
    return gt;
}
```

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense. The compiler didn't just say "no viable overloaded '='". It also specified exactly what it was trying to do that triggered a lack-of-overload-found condition. And that was... ? I'm guessing it says something about expectation of an l-value. In which case your `operator =` would be better served taking a `const` reference rather than a hot one. `nod &operator=(nod const &x)`

Comment: `nod &operator=(nod &x)` wants a non-const reference. Looks like you are using it in contexts where non-const reference can't be bound to the argument. You also didn't post the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, so I am voting to close this.

Comment: Can you show code for `graf operator~();`?

Comment: @WhozCraig Wow, that worked! Thanks a lot! But could you please explain me why taking a constant reference made it work?

Comment: You're returning a temporary object. Unless you have move semantics on the menu (and you don't), a const reference is the only thing you're going to bind it to (which you now do).

Comment: @WhozCraig I guess I have to study constants more. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nod &operator=(nod &x)` had to be changed to `nod &operator=(const nod &x)`